# Value of type char* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type “char”

Tags: c++

Tab seperated `example.txt` file:

```
1    MODEL1
2    MODEL2
3    MODEL3
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    char model[6];
    list myList;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("example.txt");

    //reading first line from file
    infile >> (int)number;
    infile >> model;
    myList.Insert({ number, model}, 1); // error here on model

    return 0;
}
```

Pseudo of myList class:

```
struct data{
    int number;
    char model[6];
};

struct Node{
    data data;
    ...
};

Node = myNode[100]

void Insert(data x, int position)
{
    myNode[position].data = x;
}
```

I have problems reading my second row of chars from `example.txt` file. How do I read MODEL1, MODEL2, MODEL3 into myList?

Comment: Besides your compilation error, you have a buffer overflow bug. When you read a string from a stream, it appends the null terminator character. Your modelnames contain 6 characters. Therefore you overflow `char model[6]` when streaming 7 characters into it.

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but you have a more serious error, namely *buffer overflow*. You declare an array of six characters, but you write *seven* characters into the array, writing out of bounds and leading to *undefined behavior*. You have forgotten that C-style strings needs an extra character to terminate the string. Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead. Incidentally using `std::string` will solve the problem you ask about as well.

Comment: In `main`, instead of declaring `int number` and `char model[6]` separately, why not declare `struct data data_item;` and read `infile >> data_item.number;` and `infile >> data_item.model`, then call `myList.Insert(data_item, 1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{number, model}` is trying to initialize the member variable `model` as a copy of the local `model`, but raw arrays can't be copy-initialized.

You'll have to use `std::string`:

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    std::string model;
    list myList;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("example.txt");

    infile >> number;
    infile >> model;
    myList.Insert({number, model}, 1);
}
```

and

```
struct data
{
    int number;
    std::string model;
};
```

This will also fix the buffer overflow bug that @user2079303 and @JoachimPileborg spotted.

---

You *can* also keep the raw array, and manually `strncpy` the local `model` array to the member `model`. However this is not advised in C++.

Comment: Line infile >> model gives error: No opperator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: std::ifstream >> std::string;

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: Works fine now, thanks. Thought that I don't need any other includes  because it had std::

Comment: No, `std::` just specifies the namespace. It doesn't import anything, only `#include` does that.